# How is the array works while in a loop?

Tags: c, arrays, loops, for-loop

i'am learning **C**,and after learning the array,i want to try something,but here comes the confusion.

i try to print a-z but there are something more("{|") been printed.and i am confused with it.

```
int count;
char ph[26];
char x;
for(count = 0, x= 'a'; count < 26 , ph[count] = x; count++ , x++)
    printf("%c",ph[count]);
```

I expect the output to be **a-z**, but the actual output is **a-|**.

Thank you and I realize that  what matters is the comma operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This for loop

```
for(count = 0, x= 'a'; count < 26 , ph[count] = x; count++ , x++)
    printf("%c",ph[count]);
```

is incorrect.

In the condition of the loop

```
count < 26 , ph[count] = x
```

there is used the comma operator. The value of the operator is the value of its second operand that is the value of the assignment  `ph[count] = x`. The first operand `count < 26` is just ignored.

As a result the loop has undefined behavior.

Rewrite the loop the following way

```
for(count = 0; count < 26; count++ )
    printf( "%c", ph[count] = 'a' + count );
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the *stopping conditional expression*

```
count < 26, ph[count] = x
```

has the value `x`, i.e. `count` probably runs past 25. This is how the *expression separator operator* `,` behaves.

If this means that you end up with an out of bounds read of `ph` (which you do on ASCII encoded platforms), the behaviour of your code is undefined.

The way you have written the loop is unnecessarily obfuscating, but if you want to stick to a similar way then writing

```
count < 26 && ph[count] = x
```

is the fix. Finally note that ASCII is not the only *encoding* supported by C, so even when you do get the program working on your platform, you have not written it in portable C.

Comment: or i can just exchange the position of "ph[count] = x" and "count < 26".

Comment: @Absolutelyrun: nope, since then you might be making an out of bounds access: the bounds check comes too late.